# Layout Issue with CSS3

Tags: html, css, layout

So let me start off by saying I'm not a designer by any means, I've tinkered with HTML and CSS a little bit here and there for various projects, but it has never been a full-time thing for me. However, I have been trying to study for the Microsoft HTML5 w/ Javascript and CSS3 exam lately using their official jump start videos, and I have run into a question that I cannot seem to find the answer to/interpret.

The question is:

```
How much space will my second column take if the definition of my grids is as follows:

.grid #mydivs > div{
            display: -ms-grid;
            -ms-grid-columns: 100px 1fr 100px;
            -ms-grid-rows: 100px 1fr 100px;
            width: 600px;
           height: 400px;
      }
```

Looking at it, I thought the answer would be 100px, but that seems to be incorrect. Could someone explain what the correct answer is here and how one might derive it? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466340.aspx, your second column will take 1fr (fraction) of the remaining width.
Knowing that your first column will use 100px and the last one 100px as well out of the total width of 600px:

The answer should be `1 fraction of 400px (600px - 100px - 100px)` or `400px`.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty strange syntax, here's the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466340.aspx I think that says that the second column is what's left of the remaining width.  So possibly 400px.

Edit:

how it work:

The fr represents a fraction of the remaining width, since there is only one fr width the value 1fr means "whatever is left", so 400px.  if there had been a 1fr, 3fr that would mean to divide the remaining width in quarters, so they would be 100px and 300px since they used 1 and 3 quarters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer; I gave the credit to cheesemacfly as he answered slightly earlier, but I still appreciate your help.

Question though, when you say if it had been 1 fr, 3fr, do you mean `-ms-grid-columns: 100px 1fr 3fr;` given that the width is `600px`. Would it automatically convert the 3fr first (i.e. column 3 is 200px and consequently 1fr is the remaining 400px for column 2)?

Comment: Actually I answered about 20 seconds earlier(the most recently edited reply appears first in the "active" view), but it's no problem he needs the points more than I do. On the fractions I meant 100px 1fr 3fr 100px, so its still dividing up 400px. the fractions divide up what is left after you remove the fixed values.